# Using ActionBarSherlock with roboguice2.0

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, roboguice

I was trying the sample roboguice project in ActionBarSherlock library. It uses roboguice2.0b4.jar (a beta release) but when i replace it with the stable release roboguice2.0.jar I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.roboguice.activity.AstroboyMasterConsole@40533b68 does not appear to be a RoboGuice context (instanceof RoboContext)
```

what can be done to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activity (AstroboyMasterConsole) must implement the RoboContext interface, means you have to extend it from one of the classes below:

[image: RoboContext implementors]

Comment: I had just changed the jar in libs from  roboguice2.0b4.jar to roboguice2.0.jar in the sample. The activity extends RoboSherlockActivity, still the illegal argument exception is coming.

Comment: Try to clean and thoroughly rebuild everything. Sometimes Eclipse may make troubles when you change libs.

Comment: got the solution: actually the samples with the roboguice project used an old version of third party https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock library in which RoboSherlockActivity did'nt implement RoboContext, using the new version solved the issue